# Android unable to load drawable image on Menu

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am following step by step instructions shared on development platform of google http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/index.html

But some how due to some reason I am not seeing ic_action_search.png on Menu bar in my simulator, though it is imported and copied on drawable-hdpi.

Listing down all options tried till now (using eclipse IDE):

1. Import image ic_action_search.png
2. Don't import image but copy it directly on folder
3. Size of image, I have copied it directly from Android_Design_Icons.zip suggested at https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html
4. Recompile project by "Clean"
5. Deleting res in bin folder
6. Deleting R.java in gen folder
7. Creating whole project altogether again
8. Changing option android:showAsAction to "never", "always", "ifRoom"
9. Placing .png file at right place
10. Not using .jpg only .png
11. Using Support library
12. Using lower case to define file names
13. Added following to menu tag,
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context="com.example.actionbar.MainActivity"
14. Added follwoing to item tag
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"

My main_activity_actions.xml looks like,

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
  <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:showAsAction="never" />
 <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      android:showAsAction="never" /></menu>
```

.... but still I cant see search image getting loaded up in menu bar. Though settings icon  shows the action_search value defined in string.xml
I am not using Support Library Setup as of now, and  android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19"

I need to show this, as there is something wrong here and as i go further I still cant load any other image.  Please advise

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `showAsAction` as `always` or `ifRoom` to show the action icons in the `menu bar`.
If you set it to `never` , it will not be shown as an `action menu`. It will only show in `PopupMenu`

Change

```
 android:showAsAction="never"
```

to

```
 android:showAsAction="always"
```

Comment: Google suggest android:showAsAction="never" and it shows Settings with it. Though I have tried it with android:showAsAction="always"

But still issue is same.... I am not able to see image getting loaded on menu bar .... any other suggestion pls ...

Answer (score 0):

append this line in your menu tag `xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`
and append these two lines in item tag

```
 yourapp:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
            yourapp:showAsAction="always"
```

i.e. use this layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <!-- Search / will display always -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
          yourapp:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
            yourapp:showAsAction="always"
          android:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Comment: Giru, here is what I did, I deleted my project and recreated with all specifications that you have defined in your blog together with what you suggested above... but I still cant see any icon getting loaded to simulator

Comment: Do you guys have any suggestion on specific types of Virtual Device

Comment: Any other suggestion please

Comment: @AmitVashistha see my edited post and reply if you still not seeing search image

Comment: output is still the same, though now I got 5 action_search String value if I click Settings

Comment: any other clues @Giru Bhai

Comment: I did that step(see result) and got success